Cors request failure in clojure application
I am learning how to use reagent clojure and I am creating a password management application with some basic crud operations as well. Right now when I try to delete a password or use my password generation function on the back end it is getting CORS requests failures no matter what I do. I will share my relevant back and front end functions and the error message.
Error message in the browser
POST
http://localhost:3000/remove-a-password
CORS Missing Allow Origin

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/remove-a-password. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 500.

Failed to remove password: 
Object { meta: null, cnt: 3, arr: (6) […], __hash: null, "cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition0$": 16647951, "cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition1$": 401412 }

Okay so here is my back end
(ns LPM.clj.routes
  (:require [compojure.core :refer [defroutes POST GET DELETE]]
            [ring.adapter.jetty :refer [run-jetty]]
            [ring.middleware.json :refer [wrap-json-body wrap-json-response]]
            [ring.middleware.cors :refer [wrap-cors]]
            [clojure.data.json :as cjson]
            [LPM.clj.user :as usr]
            [LPM.clj.pwfuncs :as pwf]
            [clojure.tools.logging :as log]))

(def current-user (atom
            {:users
             {"profile" {:userProfileName "Admin User"
                         :userLoginPassword "password123"
                         :passwords [{:pName "example"
                                      :pContent "exampleContent"
                                      :pNotes "Example note"}]}}}))
(defn remove-a-password
  [profile-name pw-to-remove]
  (swap! current-user update-in
         [:users profile-name :passwords]
         (fn [passwords]
           (let [updated-passwords (remove #(= (:pName %) pw-to-remove) passwords)]
             (log/info "Updated passwords after removal:" updated-passwords)
             updated-passwords))))
(defroutes app-routes

  ...Other working routes up here..
  
  (POST "/remove-a-password" {:keys [body]}
    (let [profile-name (:userProfileName body)
          pName (:pName body)]
      (log/info "L->Handling password removal" body)
      (usr/remove-a-password profile-name pName)
      {:status 200
       :headers {"Content-Type" "application/json"}
       :body (cjson/write-str {:message "L-> Password removed successfully"})}))
  
  (GET "/generate-a-password" [size]
    (pwf/generate-password size)))
^These two routes don't work even though I can add passwords and users


(def handler
  (-> app-routes
      (wrap-cors :access-control-allow-origin  #".*"
                 :access-control-allow-methods [:GET :POST :OPTIONS :DELETE]
                 :access-control-allow-headers ["Content-Type" "Authorization"]
                 (fn [request]
                   (let [response (handler request)]
                     (-> response
                         (assoc-in [:headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] "*")
                         (assoc-in [:headers "Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] "*")))))
      (wrap-json-body)
      (wrap-json-response)))

(defn -main [& args]
  (run-jetty handler {:port 3000 :join? false}))

^Me allowing everything conceivable


Okay and here is my relevant front end
(def user-state (r/atom {:userProfileName "nil"
                         :userLoginPassword nil
                         :passwords []}))

(defn remove-pw-request [profile-name pName]
  (ajax/POST "http://localhost:3000/remove-a-password"
    {:params {:userProfileName profile-name
              :pName pName}
     :headers {"Content-Type" "application/json"}
     :format :json
     :response-format :json
     :handler (fn [response]
                (js/console.log "Removed password:" response)
                (swap! user-state update :passwords
                       (fn [passwords]
                         (remove #(= (:pName %) pName) passwords))))
     :error-handler (fn [error]
                      (js/console.error "Failed to remove password:" error))}))

(defn generate-password-request [size]
  (let [url (str "http://localhost:3000/generate-a-password?size=" size)]
    (ajax/GET url
              {:response-format :json
               :handler (fn [response]
                          (js/console.log "Generated password:" (:password response)))
               :error-handler (fn [error]
                                (js/console.error "Failed to generate password:" error))})))

^These are my front end handlers


Here is where I call the functions in my front end:

(defn delete-pw-component [profile-name pName]
  (let [click-handler
        (fn [] (help/remove-pw-request profile-name pName))]
    [:div.remove-button-container
     [:input {:type "button"
              :id "delete-pw-component"
              :value "X"
              :style {:padding-top "0px"
                      :padding-right "4px"
                      :font-style "bold"
                      :color "#781848"
                      :cursor "pointer"
                      :transform "translate(1vw, -0.2vh)"}
              :on-click click-handler}]]))

(defn logged-in-view [profile-name]
  (let [passwords (@help/user-state :passwords)]
    [:div.main-container
     [heading-box]
     [:div
      (when (not @help/show-add-form)
        [:div
         [:h2 (str "Hello " profile-name ", you logged in at " (current-time))]
         [plus-sign-component]])
      (when @help/show-add-form
        [generation-form-box])
      (when (and (not @help/show-add-form) (empty? passwords))
        [:div
         "You have no passwords yet"])
      (when (not @help/show-add-form)
        [:ul
         (for [{:keys [pName pContent pNotes]} passwords]
           ^{:key pName}
           [:li.password-list (str "Name: " pName ", Content: " pContent ", Notes: " pNotes)
            [delete-pw-component (@help/user-state :userProfileName) pName]])])]]))


I can provide any further info necessary as well.
I tried making the POST request that has a delete function into a DELETE request and for some reason that I cannot figure out, when I do that it sends TWO failed requests back to me, so maybe that is a clue?
OPTIONS
http://localhost:3000/remove-a-password
CORS Missing Allow Origin
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/remove-a-password. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 500.
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/remove-a-password. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
Failed to remove password:
Object { meta: null, cnt: 3, arr: (6) […], __hash: null, "cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition0$": 16647951, "cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition1$": 401412 }
That is the error with DELETE instead of post for remove-a-password. I am out of ideas...
shadow-cljs - HTTP server available at http://localhost:8080
shadow-cljs - server version: 2.28.10 running at http://localhost:9630
shadow-cljs - nREPL server started on port 61115
shadow-cljs - watching build :app
[:app] Configuring build.
[:app] Compiling ...
It says this when I start with npx shadow-cljs watch app
When I try to start the server it says
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
And I think it is running...

The answer was that I actually just had unrelated issues in another one of my back end files that was causing a 500 request. If someone has similar issues they should make sure all their files at least compile.
